# Can I route DHCPv6 & Router-Advertisements through another router?

Tags: routing, ipv6, dhcpv6

I have asked this question on Super-User, though I'm not sure, it's the best place. [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1627705/can-i-route-dhcpv6-and-router-advertisements-through-another-router)

I believe this Exchange is a more appropriate place to ask:

I have a dual router setup (two routers behind each other) and I want to get IPv6 working on my Local Network.

`ISP <-> Router_1 <-> Router_2 (Unifi USG) <-> Local Network`

- Router_1 gets a global IPv6 address and also gets a Prefix-Delegation from the ISP.
- Clients directly connected to Router_1 also successfully get global IPv6 addresses.

*What I now want to achieve is that the Router-Advertisement from Router_1 is "forwarded" across the Router_2 into my Local Network.*
But I'm not sure the standards actually support that. I did find the multi-home scenarion in the RFC but I couldn't figure out if what I have in mind would actually work.

**Why I want that scenario to work anyay?** Because my Router_1 (Vodafone Station; it's a kind of crappy home-router from my ISP) does not support the further Prefix-Delegation to another router. Therefore I need to use the DHCPv6-Server that's on the Router_1 for my LAN(s).

Reading through documentation on IPv6, DHCPv6, Router Advertisements and SLAAC, I still can't seem to figure out if this is actually supported or not.

Comment: What are the router models and configurations?

Comment: I added the Router model for Router_1. Not sure what I should share regarding your request for "configuration".

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: But I am asking if the official standard (IPv6, DHCPv6, Neighbor-Discovery) supports that - not how to configure my equipment!

Comment: Enterprise-grade equipment (what is on-topic here) can usually delegate to downstream routers and do DHCP relay.

Comment: @RonMaupin But that's not the point of my question. I am asking whether the standard allows for DHCP-RAs and DHCP-Comm's to be forwarded or not. It has nothing to do with equipment. If there's an exchange that talks about standards and what they include and what not, I'm happy to post my question there, but I couldn't find any. And this Exchange seems to make sense to me.

Comment: It has everything to do with the equipment. If your equipment does not support IPv6 Prefix Delegation or DHCP relay, then you need to upgrade the equipment. I doubt most consumer-grade devices support that or what you want to do.

Comment: So, Unifi Security Gateway is not enterprise-grade then? Because it's only about the Unifi Security Gateway. To configure it the way required - IF it's actually doable.

Actually, you just gave me a good keyword : DHCP Relay. So there seems to be something that does what I want. Is that applicable to IPv6? If so, then that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I did not say either way, but not all equipment supports everything, and you claim yours does not, so you need to get equipment that does. The major enterprise-grade vendors (Cisco, Juniper, etc.) have equipment that does that. Your vendor may have some that does, even if what you have does not.

Comment: RA is a link-local protocol, it cannot be routed or forwarded. DHCP (v4 and v6) support relay. But in this case, you want a DHCPv6 server in the first router that can hand out prefixes from the PD it received as a DHCPv6 client. (this is indeed a rare feature.) I doubt your ISP will answer a relayed internal request for v6 space.